# HighStock Grouping Daily and Monthly with columns

Tags: javascript, grouping, highcharts

I have a HighStock chart (type column) that contains a value for each day. What I would like to do looks very simple, however I cannot manage to achieve it. I would like my data to appear day by day when we display one month and month by month when we display more than one month. I have 3 buttons for range selector :

```
buttons: [{
                type: 'month',
                count: 1,
                text: 'Vue par mois'
            }, {
                type: 'year',
                count: 1,
                text: 'Annee'
            }, {
                type: 'all',
                text: 'Tout'
            }]
```

I tried to play with de datagrouping options but the problem is that the default value group my data by week instead of month. I tried many solutions but nothing works :
units:

```
[[   
                            'month',
                                [1]
                            ],
                            [
                                'day',
                                [1]
                             ]
                        ]
```

The solution above for example group the data by month, even if we display for one month, resulting in a big column block on the graph.

I feel like I'm missing something but what ? I hope my explanations are understandable. Any help would really be appreciated.

Thanks in advance !

Milene

Comment: Have you tried to set day as 1, and in month as 30 ?

Comment: Yes, it keeps the value by day if I do so and display a lot mini bar when displayed by year.

Comment: You can prepare your own approximation function.